# Multithreading in C to read and print a very large file

Tags: c, multithreading, file-handling

I have a very large file to read and do the below actions.

1. Open the Large file (>50MB) and read it line by line
2. Perform some comparison action
3. Print the result of comparison
4. Return

When I perform the above sequence in a single threaded C code it works fine and now I am trying to making it faster by using Multithreading by creating 3 threads (I have a mandate to use 3 threads to make this process faster) to read and compare but I have failed in doing so as I see it simply repeats some of the comparisons.

Is there some way for me to read 3 different sections of a file using 3 threads and perform some action?

Comment: It's a good exercise to study threads. But *bear* with me, we need to see some code.

Comment: How long does your program take now?  Is the CPU at 100% when it runs?

Comment: @JohnZwinck it takes about a minute and no CPU is not at 100% however I am mandated to use 3 threads to process this.

Comment: Well, since you are talking about "lines" from the file, it must be text and not binary. In that case, have one thread reading and filling a dynamically allocated array of lines (either `char **` or if the lines are roughly the same length, `char (*)[length]`). (consider `mmap` for the file access) You need a counter accessible by each thread so the compare thread can start comparing the stored lines (if you cannot make a final comparison until all lines are read, the multi-threads are pointless). And finally a print thread outputting the results of the comparison.

Comment: You'll generally find this will be IO bound no matter how many threads you throw at it.  The only place where you're going to get performance improvement is by overlapping those slow reads with other thread(s) processing previously read data. That said, the very best performance you'll get is however fast you can simply scan in the lines from the file. Short of memory mapping the file into your address space, you simply cannot get the data any faster.

Comment: @PB22: When you say you are "mandated to use 3 threads" do you mean this is a homework assignment and the goal is to use 3 threads, or do you mean that the goal is to improve performance and your senior coworkers have told you they think that 3 threads will help?

Comment: Even mapping the file into memory seems unlikely to provide a significant improvement in running time, at least for a single pass through it.  The limiting factor is still likely to be the time it takes to read the data from their storage media.

Comment: You describe three main actions, and even separate them out into numbered points 1 - 3.  Do you suppose that it's a coincidence that the exercise asks you to use three threads to implement a solution?

Comment: "It is slow" is one thing. "I am mandated to use threads" is quite another thing. Pick one because solutions to these problems are different.

Comment: I just measured: `wc bigfile` needs about 5 seconds to scan a 100MB file. wc does not use multithreading. You must be doing something wrong (my guess: reallocation, leading to quadratic behaviour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this answer is a '**trick**' (or may be the assignment is a trick ?), as it does not really make the process faster. Answer assume standard Linux computer with reasonable (4G+) memory.

Short Answer: In any half-decent configuration, the data will move into OS buffers, and the problem is actually CPU bound, and not IO bound.

Long Answer:

While the 50MB file is 'Large' for humans, it is 'Small' for every modern computer. In reality, the data will move into the OS buffers, and will stay there, unless the system need the memory for other tasks.

Given data is in (OS) memory, the problem (other than the initial call), is not IO-bound, but CPU bound. For this 3 thread MT program will do magic. The question become how to spread the work over 3 files. Ideally, the 3 threads will divide the files into 3 (almost) equal blocks, the process each by itself.

Solution is pseudo-code, actual code will have to deal with handling of the lines that split over blocks, error checks, etc.

```
FILE *data_fp ;
static int block_size ;

main() {
   data_fp = fopen(...) ;
   int filesize = ftell(fp) ;
   block_size = filesize/6 ;

   for (int i=0 ; i<N_THREADS ; i++ ) {
       start_offset = filefize*((float i)/N_THREADS) ;
       pthread_create(search_start, ... , &start_offset) ;
   }
}

search_start(void *arg) {

   // Extract the offset to start
   long start_offset = * (long *) arg ;
   // Create separate FILE*, with separate position, buffers, etc.
   FILE *local_fp = fdopen(fileno(data_fp), "r") ;

   // Position at the thread specific offset
   fseek(local_fp, start_offset, SEEK_SET) ;

   char buff[256] ;  // max line size
   // Loop until EOF, some exit condition, or block_size characters processed
   for (long p = 0 ; p < block_size && fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), local_fp) ; p += strlen(buff)) {
       // Compare, check, whatever is needed
       ...
       if (need_to_stop) break ;
   } ;
   fclose(local_fp) ;

}
```

Probably possible to make this even faster using 'mmap'. However, question requested line processing, and given that this is not a real-life problem, not sure if it's worth the extra effort.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your replies. @dash-o thanks for the response and I think the solution is in the right direction. However, I did not understand the part in search_Start where you say create separate files, do we need to create separate files at different start indexes prior to coming into search_start ?

Comment: Clarification, those are separate file pointers (FILE * object). No data is copies. The FILE * will allow each thread to read at a different place of the input file. I've also added a messing seek. Hopefully it will make sense now

Comment: sorry to be bothering you. I was able to solve my problem using the above approach however, I am facing issues in handling of the lines that split over blocks. i.e i see words split abruptly sometimes. Is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: No problem, I will try to help - Can you provide information about the 'some comparison action' and 'Print the result' ? the adjustment will depends on the exact actions. Also, can you put a limit to the maximum line length - it will help dealing with the overlap region.